# Get specific values from nested arrays elements in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection with objects like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52ed12c144aecc4bf004d0b6"),
  "title": "myBook",
  "summary": "This is a book summary",
  "covers": [
    "http://url.com/cover1.jpg",
    "http://url.com/cover2.jpg",
  ],
  "urls": [
    "http://url.com/myBook",
    "http://url.com/myBook/option2"
  ],
  "genres": [
    "comedy",
    "romantic"
  ],
  "created_at": ISODate("2012-12-17T23:00:00Z"),
  "modify_at": ISODate("2014-02-01T15:41:48.149Z")
}
```

but I only want to get the first value from **covers** and **urls** attributes, my output json should be something like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52ed12c144aecc4bf004d0b6"),
  "title": "myBook",
  "summary": "This is a book summary",
  "covers": "http://url.com/cover1.jpg",
  "urls": "http://url.com/myBook"
  "genres": [
    "comedy",
    "romantic"
  ],
  "created_at": ISODate("2012-12-17T23:00:00Z"),
  "modify_at": ISODate("2014-02-01T15:41:48.149Z")
}
```

I think I have to use a map_reduce, but I'm not sure how I should be the query, I tried:

`db.books.mapReduce( function(){ emit(this._id, this.covers); }, function(key, values){ return values[0]; }, { out: "map_reduce_covers" } )`

But that doesn't seems work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) projection operator to control which elements of an array are included in the output.

```javascript
db.books.findOne({}, {covers: {$slice: 1}, urls: {$slice: 1}})
```

outputs:

```javascript
{
  "_id": ObjectId("52ed12c144aecc4bf004d0b6"),
  "title": "myBook",
  "summary": "This is a book summary",
  "covers": [
    "http://url.com/cover1.jpg"
  ],
  "urls": [
    "http://url.com/myBook"
  ],
  "genres": [
    "comedy",
    "romantic"
  ],
  "created_at": ISODate("2012-12-17T17:00:00-0600"),
  "modify_at": ISODate("2014-02-01T09:41:48.149-0600")
}
```

`covers` and `urls` are still arrays, and it gets more complicated if you want to also change that.